# Does Google Analytics only count a Unique Visitor if he/she lands on the index (home) page?

Tags: google-analytics

Does Google Analytics only count a Unique Visitor if he/she lands on the index (home) page?  What if the UV makes his way to a side-page of your site but never visits the home page (index page)? Would he still count as a unique visitor under Google analytics?

Comment: If my answer was helpful and answered your question feel free to mark it as the answer.

Comment: @Anagio, nice job asking for a check.  Usually the guys with 1 point dont participate properly.

Comment: If I could I would vote up his answer but that would require 15 reputation.

Answer (score 1):

No if a visitor lands on any page of your website and has not visited the site within 30 minutes they are considered a unique visitor. It doesn't matter which page they go to as long as you have Google Analytics tracking code installed.

http://analytics.blogspot.com/2007/01/absolute-unique-visitors-versus-new.html